# Adding elements to a list with SQL query and .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, list

I am new to writing console applications, and this is escaping me on how to do this.

What I am trying to do is take the query string, turn PRODUCT_TYPE_NO to PTN, then add each PTN to a list named PTNList.  There will ultimately be over 1200 PTN's, and I can run the SQL query in MS SQL server and get the information back that I need, so I know the query itself is fine.

When I step through the code, it seems to break up right before the 'while (rdr.Read())', jumping down to the 'catch', giving an `InvalidOperationException` stating 'ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.'

Like I said, I'm rather new to this, so this may sound like a basic problem for me to not catch, but any help would be appreciated.

Below is s snippet of the code, the part giving me a problem.

```
try
{
    const string connectionString = "ConnectionInfo";

    con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();

    //connect to DB to get all PTN from product_type_def
    string query = @"select PRODUCT_TYPE_NO AS PTN
                     from dbo.PRODUCT_TYPE_DEF";

    List<int> PTNList = new List<int>();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        PTNList.Add(Convert.ToInt32("PTN"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few different problems there. Firstly, you didn't tell the command about the connection. Second, you aren't actually reading from the reader at the end. The connection can be set either by passing the connection into the constructor:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
```

or by calling:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

To read the actual data, you want something like:

```
PTNList.Add(rdr.GetInt32(0));
```

Note that the command, connection and reader are all `IDisposable` and you should be using `using`.

Alternatively, use a tool like "[dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper)" to help you:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     var PTNList = con.Query<int>(query).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I figured out the rdr part, but it was the setting of the connection that was really getting.  Like I said, I thought it might be a basic or simple thing. Thanks for the help.